# Expression of Dirac delta function by integral of exponential function

Tags: conventions, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

In many QFT books including Peskin & Schroeder's and M.Schwartz's mention about Fourier transform and representation of Dirac delta function as

$\begin{align}
&f(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{ipx}\tilde{f(p)} \\
&\tilde{f(p)} = \int{d^3x}e^{-ipx}\tilde{f(x)}\\
&\delta^{(3)}(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{ipx}
\end{align}$

And i'm wonder if Dirac delta function that takes momentum as an argument would be defined as same as Dirac delta function that takes position.

$\begin{align}
\delta^{(3)}(p) = \int\frac{d^3x}{(2\pi^3)}e^{-ipx}
\end{align}$ ?

This seems legit to me since

$\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{ipx}dp = 2\pi \delta(x)
\end{align}$

for some complicated calculations.

I'm bit confused because for M.Schwartz's book says

$\begin{align}
\delta^{(4)} (x)= \int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-ikx}
\end{align}$

And Peskin & Schroeder's says

$\begin{align}
\delta^{(4)} (k)= \int\frac{d^4x}{(2\pi)^4}e^{ikx}
\end{align}$

and the sign of exponential seems irresponsible since. $\delta(x) = \delta(-x)$

Is it valid to express $\delta(x)$ and $\delta(k)$ both in that way? (And they are not Fourier dual to each other)

Comment: Duplicate : [Normalization of eigenfunction to Dirac-delta function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369159/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalization of eigenfunction to Dirac-delta function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369159/)